# What does "Mapping from a set of a real number vector n to set of symmetric matrix in a real number mxm matrix" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

In "LMI's in Control Systems-Analysis, Design, and Applications" (by Guang-Ren Duan and Hai-Hua Yu) , on page 2, it says that the LMI (linear matrix inequality):
$A(x)=A_0+x_1 A_1 + \dots x_n A_n < 0$ "is a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{S}^n$. I looked up what a mapping from one set to another means, and from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) :

"each element of one set is paired with exactly one element of the other set, and each element of the other set is paired with exactly one element of the first set."

So does this mean that A(x) is a function that takes in a vector as an input and outputs a symmetric matrix of size $m\times m$? where m=1 (since its a linear function) ?

Comment: Yes; $A$ takes as input the value $x \in \mathbb R^n$ that is a $n$-uple of reals: $x= (x_1,\ldots, x_n)$

Comment: It outputs a symmetric matrix of size $n \times n$

Comment: I assume that the $A_i$'s are $n \times n$ matrices and thus $A$ produce a "combination" of them.